# Using "always" in front of an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, hyphens

If I used "always" in front of an adjective that is preceding a noun, would I hyphenate "always" and the adjective?

Ex: "And the always-flashy Usain Bolt wins again!" as opposed to "And the always flashy Usain Bolt wins again!"

Comment: No need for a hyphen. *always* is an adverb that can modify an adjective just like any other adveb can.

Comment: No need, but not wrong either.

Answer (score 1):

It does not need to be hyphenated. Because always is a adverb, using hyphenation in that instance would be like using a hyphen in-between a noun and an adjective.

Comment: I would put one between "in" and "between"if it was being employed as a composite adjective - such as "an in-between idea". But used as you have done here, the "in" is quite superfluous anyway. I would not put one between a noun and an adjective. But I would put one between two words which together form a composite adjective - such as a "politically-polarised" country.

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly hyphenate.

The current trend in the UK is to hypenate all pre-positioned composite adjectives - "a boy with curly-black hair, a car with blue-tinted windows, a woman carrying a heavily-laden suitcase, a tree-lined walkway" etc.

This would include ones that employ adverbs, such as "a sometimes-funny comedian, or an always-busy hairdresser".

Answer (score 1):

There is an unsettled debate as to whether you should hyphenate or not in these cases with an adverb. It is a matter of stylistic choice.

However, note that there is an exception to this freedom of choice - you cannot hyphenate the adverb "very".